# A question about functions from binary inputs to binary outputs

Tags: functions, optimization, binary, function-and-relation-composition, bayesian-network

The following is a distillation of part of a larger research problem.  (I have several clunky proofs for special cases, but an elegant method for the general case is somehow escaping me.)

---

Consider a graph $G$ with nodes arranged in a pyramid:  $1$ node in the first row, $1+d$ nodes in the second, $1+2d$ nodes in the third, and so on, for $m$ rows.  Each node takes a state of either 0 or 1.

Consider any row $r < m$.  Suppose that $v$ is the $k$th node in this row, and call the $k$th through $(k+d)$th nodes in row $r+1$ the *parents* of $v$.  Let $f_v$ denote a $(1+d)$-ary function from the state assignments of these parents to the state assignment of $v$.

Let $S$ be some subset of the nodes in row $m$.  Then $f_S$ is an $|S|$-ary function that maps the state assignments of the nodes in $S$ to a state assignment for the node in row $1$.

Say that a subset $S$ of the nodes in row $m$ is *free* if there is a state assignment for the rest of row $m$ such that for any function $f_S$, there are functions $f_v$ for all $v$ that produce $f_S$ by composition.

What is a largest free subset of $G$?

---

If it is helpful, let's look at an example.  Suppose $d = 1$ and $n = 6$.  Then the following table displays an $f_S$ for $S = \{v_{3,1},v_{3,2},v_{3,3}\}$ that no combination of $f_v$ functions (for the nodes $v_{1,1}$, $v_{2,1}$, and $v_{2,2}$) can produce by composition.

[image]

$S = \{v_{3,1}, v_{3,3}\}$ is therefore a largest free subset of this graph.